# Finding burn-date of a DVD

Tags: date, iso, burning

An ISO file has been burned into a blank DVD (in a Linux OS). Is there any commands in Ubuntu to check when the DVD was burned?

I mean the date that the ISO file was burned, I do not mean the date ISO itself was created.

Comment: I don't think a DVD contains that information.  The structure of a DVD, outside the contents of the data track, is basically just the table of contents (which says where the data track starts and ends) and error-correction data.  And the data track is just the contents of the ISO file.

Answer (score 2):

ISO 9660 ?

Try `dd if=/dev/sr0 bs=1 skip=33581 count=17 | hexdump -C`

Example output:

```
00000000  32 30 31 32 30 38 32 33  31 37 31 33 34 37 30 30  |2012082317134700|
00000010  00                                                |.|
```

Comment: Is that going to be the burn date? Or the date that the ISO filesystem was created?

Comment: It's defined as "The standard specifies the field Volume Creation Date and Time as a numerical representation of the moment of the volume's creation, written to the 814th through 830th byte of the Primary Volume Descriptor".

Comment: It seems it just reveals the date the ISO was created.